# Execute code using a class with a "with" statement, but don't execute code until certain function is run?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I execute code using a class with a "with" statement, but don't execute code until certain function is run?

For example if I have the class:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = "baz"

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, x, y, z):
        return None

    def run(self):
        # Start running code inserted into __enter__?
```

And I used the class like:

```py
bar = Foo()

with bar as f:
    print(f.bar)
    # Don't execute this code until run() is called

bar.run()
# Now execute the code that was inserted into the with statement above
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you put the code into a function and pass it in to either `Foo`'s constructor, or into the `run` method?

Comment: If that's not possible, is there any particular reason you can't just put the `with` block after the call to `bar.run()` in your code? Maybe you can show us a real-world example, because I can't really understand why you would put the `with` block before the call to `bar.run()` if you want it to run after.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, the way your code is currently written. However, you effectively want `bar.run()` to be called from `Foo.__enter__`.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, pre=None):
        self.bar = "baz"

    def __enter__(self):
        self.run()
        return `self`

    def __exit__(self, x, y, z):
        return None

    def run(self):
        # Start running code inserted into __enter__?


bar = Foo()

with bar as f:
    print(f.bar)
```

Comment: I think the OP means to defer the running of the code enclosed in the `with bar as f:` block until `bar.run` is called, at a point of time after the context manager exits. You code simply calls the `run` method upon the entrance of the context manager and proceeds to run the code enclosed in the `with` block, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: I know that's what he *wants*, but short of using `introspect` to essentially rewrite the code on the fly, `__enter__` can't do this. It doesn't see the body of the `with` statement. I'm trying to provide an alternative that *can* be used to simulate the desired outcome.

Comment: Though I do realize there's one possibly significant difference here: in the question, `__exit__` would run *before* `run`; here, it will run after. Also, it's not clear if `with` is really wanted for its bracketing behavior, rather than an attempt at just capturing a block of code to execute later.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the code inside the with block gets executed only during the execution of the with block. It's not, for example, passed as a closure to the context manager.

If you want that behaviour, you could possibly use a decorator and a local function declaration instead of a with block.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback
        self.bar = 'baz'
    def run(self):
        # Setup goes here.
        try:
            self.callback(self)
        finally:
            # Cleanup goes here.
            pass

@Foo
def bar(f):
    print(f.bar)

bar.run()
```

That's as close to your example as I can get, names included. I think perhaps applying the constructor directly as a decorator is a bit ungainly - you might prefer to have a separate decorator function to call and return a class instance, but you get the general idea.